# EBADF while recv after epoll_wait

Tags: linux, recv, epoll

i've got a following problem: i have a epoll code which receives connections:

```
while (1) {
    int nfds = epoll_wait(epollfd, events, 4096, -1);
    if (nfds == -1) {
        if (errno == EINTR)
            continue;
        perror("epoll_wait");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < nfds; i++) {
        if (events[i].data.fd == server_sock) {
            client_sock = accept(server_sock,
                         (struct sockaddr *)&client_name,
                         (socklen_t *)(&client_name_len));

        if (client_sock == -1) //server overloaded
            continue;

        ev.events = EPOLLIN | EPOLLERR;

#ifdef CORE_NONBLOCKING_SOCKETS
        Arch::set_nonblocking(client_sock);
        ev.events |= EPOLLET; //input data and connection closing
#endif


#ifdef EPOLLRDHUP
        ev.events |= EPOLLRDHUP ;//
#else
        //for old libraries
        ev.events |= EPOLLHUP;//
#endif

        ev.data.fd = client_sock;

        if (epoll_ctl(epollfd, EPOLL_CTL_ADD, client_sock, &ev) == -1) {
            perror("epoll_ctl: client_socket");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        accept_request(client_sock);

        } else {

#ifdef EPOLLRDHUP
            if (events[i].events & EPOLLRDHUP) {
                std::cout << "EPOLLRDHUP on " << events[i].data.fd << std::endl;
                listener->disconnectDriver(events[i].data.fd);
            }
#else
            if (events[i].events & EPOLLHUP) {
                std::cout << "EPOLLHUP on " << events[i].data.fd << std::endl;
                listener->disconnectDriver(events[i].data.fd);
            }
#endif
            if (events[i].events & EPOLLIN) {
                std::cout << "debug EPOLLIN on " << events[i].data.fd << std::endl;
                accept_request(events[i].data.fd);
            }

            if (events[i].events & EPOLLERR) {
                std::cout << "debug EPOLLERR on " << events[i].data.fd << std::endl;
                listener->disconnectDriver(events[i].data.fd);
            }


        }
    }
```

when i received input connection i trying to read all buff data:

```
void get_all_buf(int sock, std::string & inStr) {
int n = 1;
int total = 0;

char c;
char temp[1024*1024]; 

bzero(temp, sizeof(temp));

do {
#ifdef CORE_NONBLOCKING_SOCKETS
    timespec time_to_wait;
    time_to_wait.tv_nsec = 10000000;
    time_to_wait.tv_sec = 0;
    timespec tm;

    time_t begin = time(NULL);
    do {
#endif

        n = recv(sock, &temp[total], sizeof(temp), 0);

#ifdef CORE_NONBLOCKING_SOCKETS
        nanosleep(&time_to_wait, &tm); 
        time_t end = time(NULL); 
        if ((end - begin) > MAX_CLIENT_TIME) {
            inStr = std::string();
            return;
        }
    } while (n < 0 && errno == EAGAIN); //nonblocking sockets in edge-triggered mode
#endif

    if (n > 0) {
        total += n;
    } else if (n == 0) {
        //TODO: error handling
        //debug
        std::cout << "possibly no one byte was received" << std::endl;
        break;
    } else if (n < 0) {
        //TODO: error handling
        //debug
        std::cout << "error while receiving data" << std::endl;
        if (errno == EBADF) {
            std::cout << "recv returns with EBADF: " << strerror(errno) << std::endl;
        } else if (errno == EFAULT) {
            std::cout << "recv returns with EFAULT: " << strerror(errno) << std::endl;
        } else if (errno == EINTR) {
            std::cout << "recv returns with EINTR: " << strerror(errno) << std::endl;
        } else if (errno == EINVAL) {
            std::cout << "recv returns with EINVAL: " << strerror(errno) << std::endl;
        }
        //end debug
        break;
    }

} while (!strstr(temp, "</packet>")); 
inStr = temp;
};
```

within `accept_request` function. but sometime i get following in my debug output:

```
packet type='connect'
size of vector<Driver> in getDriversWithMoney is 1
epoll_wait detected activity of 164 counter i = 0 nfds = 1
EPOLLRDHUP on 164
disconnectDriver (fd = 164)
driver 1 disconnected
debug EPOLLIN on 164
error while receiving data
recv returns with EBADF: Invalid file descriptor
```

which means that someone was connected first than disconnected and when he's trying to connect again `recv` returns `EBADF`. what i did wrong? please help me.

**P.S.** on `EPOLLRDHUP` i just close file descriptor. `epoll` man says it's ok, because `epoll` removes closed fd from `epoll_wait` queue by itself.

Comment: Try getting a `strace` log of the problem.

Comment: the problem is this situation is not regular. it's became up after some time.

Comment: That's precisely where strace is useful -- it shows what input to your program triggered it to behave the way it does.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When the remote host closes the socket, `epoll()` reports both a `HUP` and an `EPOLLIN` for the file descriptor.

You check for `EPOLLRDHUP` first, and close the socket; then you check for `EPOLLIN`, find that too, and try to call `recv()`.  Since the socket has been closed, the file descriptor is no longer valid, and you get `EBADF` (the closed socket is removed from the `epoll` set, so *subsequent* `epoll_wait()` calls won't return it; but for the `epoll_wait()` that has already returned it's too late - the `EPOLLIN` is already waiting in your `events[i]`.

You need to stop checking for events after you call `disconnectDriver()` (if it closed the file descriptor):

```
        if (events[i].events & EPOLLRDHUP) {
            std::cout << "EPOLLRDHUP on " << events[i].data.fd << std::endl;
            listener->disconnectDriver(events[i].data.fd);
            continue;
        }
```